# Preparing to install Ubuntu fails because it only "sees" usb capacity, not internal hd

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS from a USB. I have to hit F12 during the boot, else it goes to windoze. but after F12, then select the usb, and select install. During the install (after connecting or not to wifi), it says "Preparing to install Ubuntu" and in white area it says "You need at least 8.5 GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has only 7.9GB." and sits there, continue button is not selectable.

This is an 8GB usb, so why can't it install on to my 1TB HD?

Aside I want to set up dual boot Windows 10 (already installed) on Dell 7510.

Comment: Please share the output of sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

Comment: I'm in the same boat and when I run this command, it only displays the usb disk.
sda / sda1 -> 7.5GB /cdrom
So I guess I need to look around to mount my hdd drive.